# the system was unable to find the specified registry key

Tags: python

I run this dos command:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{824293FD-32E2-4DAA-BC28-166C140543BE}\InprocServer32 /ve
```

and successfullly get a value.
In the same terminal, when I use python as below:

```
cmd = "reg query HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\{824293FD-32E2-4DAA-BC28-166C140543BE}\\InprocServer32 /ve"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
```

it fails with this error:

> > > ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

I'm using the same terminal which is opened as admin.
I even tried puting this in a x.bat file and called x.bat in a python subprocess...still the same error.
The reg key has read permission for all users and full control for admin.
This is happening on windows server 2008R2 with python 2.7.

Also I've had no luck with _winreg so any ideas how to solve this problem by running the batch command within python?

To make it clear: it works in a dos terminal, but fails in python!

Moreover, I tried another key:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\XML
```

and this one works. One thing I've noticed is that the key that has this problem has Read permission checked and disabled while this latter key has read permission checked and enabled (can be changed).

Comment: If you get the same results from a .bat file as from your Python script, this probably isn't a problem with Python, `subprocess`, etc., which means asking it as a Python programming question isn't likely to get you the best chance of an answer…

Comment: @abarnert sorry, I clarified above.

Comment: You say "I know this is happening to others as well", but you provide a link to a question where the `reg` command didn't work directly from the prompt (or from a `.bat` file), and where the problem was (unquoted) spaces in the path. So… why do you think the same thing is happening to other people? And, if you think it _is_ the same problem, why do you think the same answer isn't an answer for you?

Comment: ok, I removed the link. However, that other issue initially did not say anything about python but later in the comments the auther revealed that the command was being run in python. Perhaps, I misunderstood, so I modified my posting.

Answer (score 6):

I realized that I've seen this problem before...
solution: disabling wow64 redirect

change reg to %Windir%/sysnative/reg.exe

```
cmd = "%Windir%/sysnative/reg.exe query HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\{824293FD-32E2-4DAA-BC28-166C140543BE}\\InprocServer32 /ve"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
```

what's more, I managed to do it with _winreg:

```
import _winreg
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{824293FD-32E2-4DAA-BC28-166C140543BE}\InprocServer32', 0, _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY + _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
print _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "")
```